# convert row data into columns in sql server

Tags: sql

I am working to create a report for our users which provides the data as to what questions and answers users answered for a certain conference. The questions for each conference are unique, so I don't know in advance the number of questions.
My data is currently showing up as follows

[image]

I want the data to be laid out this way

[image]

currently I'm using max case to accomplish this, but as mentioned before all conferences have varying degrees of sessions, so I have to change my query every time for each conference to ensure that the correct question_id and session_id is being used. 
There's gotta be a better way...please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: mssql 2012, or is a previous version?  The term you are looking for is 'pivot', though the way you have the sessions in here will be interesting to configure.

Comment: I am running mssql 2008r2

Comment: Any ideas how to approach this...or if I need to 'lower my requirements' for this.

Comment: What you are looking for is known as a 'pivot'...if those column names are set in your results (only 2 question/answer and 5 sessions) then it's pretty straight forward.  If you are looking for dynamic column names, then this is a bit more complicated.

Comment: @twelfth how complicated...what does it involve?